# Empty files entering into Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I have made where the user can select their photo and post it. My problem is that when the internet is slow it takes time to upload to the parse cloud, but sometimes instead of image empty files are added to the parse because of that my app crashes. What's wrong?

```
@IBOutlet var profileimage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var addimageText: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var imageMessage: UITextField!



@IBAction func addimage(sender: AnyObject) {
    var imagePicker:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
       imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
     profileimage.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    addimageText.titleLabel?.text = "Change"
}

func SwipeDown(){
    var swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")

    swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  SwipeDown()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true;
}

func dismissKeyboard(){
    self.imageMessage.resignFirstResponder()
}



@IBAction func uploadbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var imageText = imageMessage.text



    if profileimage.image == nil{
        println("image not uploaded")
        var alertview:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        alertview.title = "Photo Upload Fail!"
        alertview.message = "Please Select The Image";
        alertview.delegate = self
        alertview.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alertview.show()


    } else {
     var images1 = PFObject(className: "images")
        images1["imageText"] = imageText
        images1["uploader"] = PFUser.currentUser()
        images1.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (success: Bool,error: NSError?)-> Void in

            if error == nil {
                var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileimage.image)
                var parseimagefile = PFFile(data: imageData)
                images1["imageFile"] = parseimagefile
                images1.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
                    (success: Bool, error:NSError?)-> Void in

                    if error == nil{
                    println("image uploaded")
                        var alertview:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                        alertview.title = "Photo Uploaded "
                        alertview.message = "Photo Uploaded Successfully";
                        alertview.delegate = self
                        alertview.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                        alertview.show()
                       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("imagetohome", sender: self)


                    }else {
                        println(error)
                        var alertview:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                        alertview.title = "Photo Upload Failed!"
                        alertview.message = "Photo Uploaded Unsuccessfully";
                        alertview.delegate = self
                        alertview.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                        alertview.show()

                    }

                }

            }else {
                 println(error)
                var alertview:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                alertview.title = "Photo Upload Failed!"
                alertview.message = "Connection Failure";
                alertview.delegate = self
                alertview.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alertview.show()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: post your image upload code

Comment: @preetam now you check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are uploading image depending upon response of object save, may be because of it, some times it won't get success call for image upload.
Try it independently and let me know does it works,

```
@IBAction func uploadbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
var imageText = imageMessage.text



if profileimage.image == nil{
    println("image not uploaded")
    var alertview:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    alertview.title = "Photo Upload Fail!"
    alertview.message = "Please Select The Image";
    alertview.delegate = self
    alertview.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alertview.show()


} else {
    var images1 = PFObject(className: "images")
    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileimage.image)
    var parseimagefile = PFFile(data: imageData)
    images1["imageFile"] = parseimagefile
    images1.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (success: Bool, error:NSError?)-> Void in

        if error == nil{
            println("image uploaded")
            var alertview:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertview.title = "Photo Uploaded "
            alertview.message = "Photo Uploaded Successfully";
            alertview.delegate = self
            alertview.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertview.show()
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("imagetohome", sender: self)


        }else {
            println(error)
            var alertview:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertview.title = "Photo Upload Failed!"
            alertview.message = "Photo Uploaded Unsuccessfully";
            alertview.delegate = self
            alertview.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertview.show()

        }

    }
    images1["imageText"] = imageText
    images1["uploader"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    images1.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (success: Bool,error: NSError?)-> Void in

        if error == nil {


        }else {
            println(error)
            var alertview:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alertview.title = "Photo Upload Failed!"
            alertview.message = "Connection Failure";
            alertview.delegate = self
            alertview.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alertview.show()
        }
    }

}
}
}
```